# Heart "Like" button for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I came across this site (http://demo.themezilla.com/memo/post-formats) and I'm trying to figure out how the "Heart like" button was achieved. Can anyone help explain how "liking" the heart works?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Themezilla.com has developed one such plugin called ZillaLikes, through which they achieve this **Heart Like** Functionality.

Please check this link to see http://www.themezilla.com/plugins/zillalikes/

Plugin is **free to download**, so you can download it and use it for your site.

Comment: It does not have an option to unlike a post once you like it. Is there any other plugin that can like and unlike the posts.